# Number of ways of choosing five numbers of the form $10a + b$, where $1 \leq a, b \leq 5$, with conditions

Tags: combinatorics

Let $N$ be the number of ways of choosing a subset of $5$ distinct numbers from the set
$$ \left\{10a+b:1\leq a\leq 5,1 \leq b \leq 5 \right\}$$
where $a,b$ are integers such that no two have the same tens digit and no two have the same units digit.

What is the remainder when $N$ is divided by $73$?

Comment: What is "PNC" ?

Comment: I'm confused. First you say that $1 \leq a \leq 5$ and $1\leq b \leq 5$ and then you say that "no two have the same tens digit", meaning that the "tens" digit in $a$ and $b$ should be different. But it should be $0$ in both cases. Did I understand this wrong?

Comment: Permutations N Combinations

Comment: So what does the "N" mean?

Comment: The set is of the two digit numbers i.e.

Comment: N is just abbreviation for and

Comment: 11,12,13,14,15,21...,54,55

Comment: You are to choose an element in such a way that from this set of two digit numbers. Which satisfy the above conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose first number in 25 ways, the second in 16 (4 possibilities for unit digit and 4 possibilities for tens digit), the third in 9, the fourth in 4 and the last is obliged. So since $25*16*9*4*1=(5*4*3*2*1)^2=120^2$ and in this way you are counting with order (clearly $\{11,22,33,44,55\}$ is the same of $\{22,33,44,55,11\}$) you have to divide by number of permutation of five elements so: $N=120^2/5!=120\cong 47 mod73$

Comment: Thanks for the soln.